# Format (remove) HDD volume that is visible in Windows 7 Disk Management but not diskpart.exe

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, lenovo-laptop, diskpart

I'm trying to get iRST working on a SSD I installed in my lenovo u410.

As part of that process, I created a hibernation partition and was fiddling around with RAID/AHCI settings. I managed to make my computer unbootable. No sweat, I just restored it with Lenovo's 1 key system.

Now, however, I can't do anything with that hybernation partition! I can see it:
[image: Disk Manager View]

(It's the 7.81 GB partition).

But when I try to delete it in Diskpart.exe to reclaim the space and try the formatting again I only see this:
[image: Diskpart View]

I can't do anything with the partition in Disk Management either. Right clicking only shows the 'help' option.

Can anyone suggest a way to edit these partitions with windows or, at least, reccomend a program that might help me fix this?

Note, I'd rather not delete the 16 GB OEM partition that I believe holds the backup for this computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can recommend **Easeus Partition Magic** for this.

You download the free Home Version here:

http://www.partition-tool.com/download.htm

Easeus can handle hidden and locked partitions.

Comment: Wow, thanks. I've been very skeptical of third party managers, hence the trust of my question was using internal windows tools, but this was really a very good program.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, there are some freeware third party partition managers available. Examples that come to mind include EaseUS and Paragon. Do a Google search for 'freeware partition manager'

I would recommend using a Linux Live CD with gparted to perform this task. You will see the partitions mounted as /dev/sda1, /dev/sda2, etc. and you can delete the partitions from the partition manager GUI included on the Live CD. http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php